# SSL connection PHP MYSQL SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I am new in php and I have a problem with SSL connection to a database.

How to add `mysqli_ssl_set()` parameters from  web  hosting

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_ssl_set(connection,key,cert,ca,capath,cipher);
```

Make sure your openSSL is enabled otherwise all will go in vain.

As per the parameters, these are given pretty much detailed [Here.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_ssl_set.asp)

Hope you will do better research before posting in SO from next time. Cheers.